# sending stream to browser directly from node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an java end point which returns stream something like below.

```
@GET
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "application/vnd.ms-excel"})
    @Path("/export")
    @Override
    public void getStream(@QueryParam("names") List<String> names,@Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = getData(articleTypeCodes);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=template.xlsx");
            response.getOutputStream().write(convertWorkbookToOutputStream(workbook));
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (ManagerException | IOException ex) {
            throwException(ex);
        }
    }
```

I have an express app which calls the above api.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    function getData(link){
        console.log(link);
        var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhReq.open("GET", link, false);
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("Authorization",".......");
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
        xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhReq.send(null);
        return xhReq;
    }   
    res.send(getData("http://localhost:8000/api/export?names=bags").responseText);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

when I tried localhost:3000/ on browser.I see unreadable text on the screen.

How to directly redirect the stream to browser and browser can translate it to .xlsx file?

Comment: Err… sounds like the "unreadable text" **is** the xlsx file (which is a specially formatted zip file, so if expressed as text is unreadable)

Comment: Wouldn't `XMLHttpRequest` be asynchronous

Comment: @adeneo — Not if you set the third argument to `open()` to `false`

Comment: Why all the `"Content-Type","application/json"` stuff when there is no JSON anywhere near the code?

Comment: @Quentin No need of that actually.But that won't cause problem. And yes I believe "unreadable text" is the xlsx file.I can get the excel when I hit the end point from browser. I could not figure out how to pipe it using node in between

Comment: Hint: `Content-Type`.

Comment: @Quentin thanks that works..Works with .pipe(res) as well